# encryption password by script failed

Tags: shell-script, shell, encryption, postfix, mariadb

I am testing to add a user to my database with a bash script! my code for my bash script is :

```bsh
mysql -u root <<MYSQL_SCRIPT
USE mail_server;
INSERT INTO mail_server.virtual_users

  (`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)

VALUES

  ('1', '1', ENCRYPT('test@test', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'test@test.com');

MYSQL_SCRIPT
```

when i run my script the user is saved but the password is saved in the database as '0 *' !!! all my user password gets password 0 * hope someone can help me

Comment: Please edit your post to use a code-block (enclose in three back-ticks) around your code and remove the `*` characters so we can see what you are really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that whithin a here-document (the `<<SOMETHING` thing), `$`, `\` and `` ` `` have a special meaning.

To avoid this, you should switch to a version of the here-document where these characters are no longer special, by quoting any part of the first delimiter.
Examples are any of these:

```
mysql -u root <<\MYSQL_SCRIPT
MYSQL_SCRIPT
mysql -u root <<'M'YSQL_SCRIPT
MYSQL_SCRIPT
mysql -u root <<MYSQL_SCRIP\T
MYSQL_SCRIPT
mysql -u root <<MY"SQL_SC"RIPT
MYSQL_SCRIPT
mysql -u root <<'MYSQL_SCRIPT'
MYSQL_SCRIPT
```

Comment: thanx it help me !!!

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, please accept the answer

Comment: i dont know how !!??

Comment: There is a grey checkbox below the answer's points on the left that you can click

Comment: @RayenBenSaid look at this answer explaining how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work